# Add link referenced to ItemID to displayform.aspx

Tags: 2013, version-history

Is there any way to add version history link (bellow code) on `displayform.aspx` as a content webpart?

```
<a href="#" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog( {url: '/_layouts/Versions.aspx?list={list guid}&ID={item id}&IsDlg=1'} ); return false;">version history</a>
```

Comment: Any help from my answer?

Answer (score 4):

## BUILT IN THINGS

Version history is already in ribbon of a `displayform.aspx`.

[image]

It is disabled by default. If you want to enable it, the go to **list setting** --> **Versioning Settings** and enable **Create a version each time you edit an item in this list**.

[image]

## CUSTOMIZATION

Did not find any **API** for version history *URL* yet but you can construct it manually. There is a pattern in version history *URL*. Let me explain it now.

Decode any existing version history *URL* using `decodeURIComponent()`.

```
decodeURIComponent('%7B233AE45E-F581-4420-B069-B7A74D368B13%7D&FileName=%2FLists%2FTender%20List%2F2_%2E000&Id=2&Source=...ender%2520List%2FAllItems%2Easpx')
```

It will result something like following.

```
{233AE45E-F581-4420-B069-B7A74D368B13}&FileName=/Lists/Tender List/2_.000&Id=2&Source=https://yourTenat.sharepoint.com/Lists/Tender%20List/AllItems.aspx
```

So what are the things in above *URL*, let me explain.

`{233AE45E-F581-4420-B069-B7A74D368B13}` is the `GUID` Id of your list. So declare a hard coded variable named `listGuidId` as this value will not change ever.

```
var listGuidId = '{233AE45E-F581-4420-B069-B7A74D368B13}';
```

`FileName=/Lists/Tender List` this is the `FileName`. You can construct it by following way.

```
    var fileName = _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath
                     .substr(0,_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

To get this `2_.000&Id=2` portion, you need the Id of your item.

```
var itemId = GetUrlKeyValue('ID');
```

So the final *URL* should look like following

```
var versionHistory = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl 
                        + '/_layouts/15/Versions.aspx?list=' 
                        + String.format('{0}&FileName={1}{2}_.000&Id={3}',
                        listGuidId,fileName,itemId,itemId);
```

Now your link should look like

```
<a href="#" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog( {url: versionHistory + '&IsDlg=1'} ); return false;">version history</a>
```